# How to use dache's CacheClient in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, distributed-cache, dache

I'm using `ironyx/dache` for distributed caching.
I created a singleton object of `CacheClient` and using it in the current project.

```
internal class CacheClientSingleton
{
    private static CacheClient _instance;
    public static CacheClient GetInstance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new CacheClient()); }
    }

    private CacheClientSingleton() { }
}
```

Is it OK this using of dache's CacheClient or ... ?

Comment: This is totally fine. The `CacheClient` is designed to be a singleton / shared instance and is totally thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CacheClient` is intended to be used as a singleton. In prior versions of Dache, the XML comments did not properly indicate this. Your code is optimal.